# Perform Basic Authentication cURL request using API

Tags: curl

I would like to perform a cURL request using the API of Joomla 3.4 using the POST method. I have following code, but keep getting a 401 error.

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ":" . $pass),
    'X-Auth-Token' => urlencode($auth_token),
    'Content-Length' => urlencode(strlen($app_xml)),
);

$options = new Joomla\Registry\Registry();

$http = JHttpFactory::getHttp($options);
$http->setOption(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$http->setOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $app_xml);
$http->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$http->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = $http->post($url, $app_xml);
```

Using the following vanilla cURL request, it works and gives back a 200-response:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ":" . $pass),
    'X-Auth-Token: ' . urlencode($auth_token),
    'Content-Length: ' . urlencode(strlen($app_xml)),
);

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $app_xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Anything I'm doing wrong here in the Joomla-part of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, by just adding `$headers` to the post call, it now works, so I took out `$http->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);` and changed the code to the following:

```
if (JHttpTransportCurl::isSupported()) {

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ":" . $pass),
        'X-Auth-Token' => urlencode($auth_token),
        'Content-Length' => urlencode(strlen($app_xml)),
    );

    $options = new Joomla\Registry\Registry();

    $http = JHttpFactory::getHttp($options);
    $http->setOption(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $http->setOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $app_xml);
    $http->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = $http->post($url, $app_xml, $headers);

    # Carry on with saving reference if correct HTTP code is returned
    if ($response->code == 200 || $response->code == 100) {
        # Do something here, it was a successful call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, Joomla requires a session token to accept a form post. Thus, a first request must get the token and submit it along the rest of the fields.

Comment: I don't understand how this will assist in the cURL request going through correctly. The system I'm submitting to will not use the token and might decline my application straight-away.